# Onelogin SAMLResponse api request

Tags: api, saml, onelogin

I'm creating automated integration tests for SSO process.
I'm new with SAML concept and probably my understanding of how it works inaccurate or wrong at all.

We chose to use OneLogin as IdP. Steps to automate:

1. User request target resource without credentials. For example `my-api.com/v1/cats`

   - Verify user has been redirected to `https://{app}.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/{app-id}?SAMLRequest={request}`
2. User login to SSO

   - Verify user has been redirected to POST `my-api.com/v1/saml/consume` with SAMLResponse inside body
   - Verify POST `my-api.com/v1/saml/consume` with right SAMLResponse give user service provider token and then redirect to initial url - `my-api.com/v1/cats`

And I'm stuck on step 2: "user login to SSO". I want to do it using onelogin API, not webform. But I didn't find documentation for it. I inspected network calls while I perform login using `https://{my-app}.onelogin.com/login` page.

After I fill email and password and click "Login" button 
1. POST request to `https://{my-app}.onelogin.com/sessions` with form-data `authenticity_token={token}&email={email}&password={password}&commit=Log%20in&_=`
2. Onelogin redirect user to make GET request to `https://{app}.onelogin.com/trust/saml2/http-post/sso/{app-id}?SAMLRequest={request}`(this is initial url generated by our service provider)
3. User redirected to `my-api.com/v1/saml/consume`

I tried to do POST to `https://{my-app}.onelogin.com/sessions` with same body as in step 1 using postman but I retrieve

> 422: UNPROCESSABLE CHANGES. Maybe you tried to change something you don't have access to.

My question: is it possible to retrieve SAMLResponse using Onelogin API? And is process I described right?

Answer (score 1):

SAML request from OneLogin or any other IDp is a form post with SAMLRequest in the body of the request. The user is going to bounce (redirect) from their site to yours. Once at your site you validate the SAMLrequest and you will use the nameid  to authenticate the user and you are done.

So you won't retrieve the response using OneLogin API, it is always a form POST from the IDp.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a redirect, user will always leave your app and go to Onelogin.

When using SAML, the flow is always like redirect from SP to IDP and after successful authentication, IDP will POST SAML Response to SP's ACS URL.

If you don't want user to redirect, then you can use OneLogin's Authentication API. But that will not be SAML flow.

Reference: https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/login-user-via-api